# Best way for iPad Table View to mimic HTML tables?

Tags: xcode, ipad, uitableview

Using iPad's Table View I need to mimic as closely as possible a table that looks like...

```
  RW     Length (ft)      Headwind (+kt)
o     14     5,000            9
o     23     5,290            3
o     32     5,000           -9
o     5      5,290           -3
```

where the "o" on the left are similar to HTML radio buttons. This function selects one of four runways to be used in flight calculations. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little dated but have a look at [this](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/) tutorial for creating and using custom cells in a UITableView. You can design the UI for the cells in Xcode at designtime which simplifies laying out your cells.